# Delphi / SQL Server : unique session identifiers for purging records

Tags: sql-server, delphi, record, delphi-xe3

We want to use `ADOConnection` in a programme.

In other softwares we can use the "session" (connection) id in the actual session, and we can list the actual (other) connections too.

We used this feature for purge permanent data from special tables if the program terminated incorrectly.

Sometimes we used real records to sign something. In the prior DBs we have more options to purge them.

1. Another transaction in same connection which held the records and "nowait" option to check the real locks (is alive or not).
2. Database level triggers (on connected, on disconnecting) to purge something.
3. Unique session id + access the session list to determine the session would exists or not.
4. Global (but session based) objects that would removed at the end of the session, but we could check their existence.

In SQL Server I don't know how to do this. As I see in this DB:

a.) 
we don't have a real unique session id.

b.)
we don't have public temporary table with records which will have removed at the end of the session.

c.)
we wouldn't list the connected sessions (connections) which linked the actual session somehow (by id, by something to make difference on same username but another application).

d.)
ADO have one transaction by connection, and the transaction is seems to be blocking. We don't want to doubling the connections for this function only.

I.)
As I see only global temporary tables could help, if the name could contain the tablename + keyvalue.

For example:

"bill_head_ID28338328" table existence is meaning (sign) that somebody locked the key 28338328.

If this connection terminated abnormally, it's global temp tables'll have vanished at the end.

II.)
Or it's a same thing if I have a table named "living_connections".

Every connection inserts a GUID based id into this table + create a global temporary table named "LIVCON_" + GUID.

Normally the programme purges the own records from the "living_connections" at the end.
But we have an "autopurging" function.

This could list the living_connections, and check for all global temp table with same GUID.
If it wouldn't find it, it's meaning that connection died somehow.

Then we could purge this record, and all linked records.

But maybe it's a wrong idea.

What do you think? Do you have any good idea to check what connection alive and what 
permanent signs are valid?

Thank you for any help, advance, link, etc.

---

Some extension:
MS-SQL server might use TCP/IP (socket) connection parameters to determine which client alive. If the connection died abnormally, server might use the default keepalive parameter, which is 2 hours... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS SQL have SPID + ConnectionTime.
These mixed values are enough unique to use them as key, and check which session data alive, and which is dead...